# IEnumerable parser class design

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, ienumerable, dicom

I'm creating a class that can read from a dicom file. This is basically a binary file filled with a lot of objects. I want to create a solid class that can do this. So I've designed the following.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Medicom
{
    public class DDocument : IEnumerable<DDataElement>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new DDocument from a file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The path of the file to load </param>
        /// <returns>An DDocument that contains the Dicom information from the file</returns>
        public static DDocument Load(string path)
        {
            return DDocument.Load(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new XDocument instance by using the specified stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream that contains the Dicom information.</param>
        /// <returns>An DDocument that contains the Dicom information from the stream.</returns>
        public static DDocument Load(Stream stream)
        {
            //Logic here to read the whole stream and List<DDataElement> Data with all the data
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a list with MetaInformation containing DDataElements
        /// </summary>
        public List<DDataElement> Data
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enumerator that can be used to iterate through the DDocument
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>An IEnumerator that can be used to iterate through the DDocument</returns>
        public IEnumerator<DDataElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (DDataElement dataElement in Data)
            {
                yield return dataElement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to know what you think of it. Are there any changes you would make in this class?

Comment: What is the point of having a List of DataElement that's a property on the IEnumerable of the same sequence?

Comment: Don't forget to add the non-generic IEnumerable implementation (your compile should warn you about this).  Make it an explicit implementation to favor clients using the generic implementation by default.  This non generic method can just forward to the generic one.

Comment: Hmm I've never heared about an explicit implementation. What's that?

Comment: He means adding an `object GetEnumerator()` method that just calls `IEnumerable<DDataElement> GetEnumerator()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

First, you should close the `FileStream` when you're done with it:

```
public static DDocument Load(string path)
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) {
        return DDocument.Load(fs); 
    }
}
```

Second, the `List` already has a perfectly good `IEnumerable`! You should use it!

```
public IEnumerator<DDataElement> GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator<DDataElement>)Data.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of recommendations, I would make your class names more meaningful. DicomDocument and DicomElement are just more descriptive and anyone else working with your code will immediately know what they are (especially if they are familiar with the DICOM structure).

Comment: Thanks these are the replies im looking for. I've changed them right away.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask yourself a few more questions about how consumers of this class will access the data in the class:

- Do they require random access to the DicomDataElements in your list?  Or will they simply enumerate over the list?
- If you allow random access, how will you search the list for the correct DicomDataElement?
- Will you allow the user to insert or add DicomDataElements into the list?
- Are you intending to support writing the file back out to disk again?  Ie, do you have to reconstruct the tags in the correct order?

What I'm getting at is that you probably want a more robust way to store your DicomDataElements within the DicomDocument, and you probably want other ways to access the tags other than through the IEnumerable.  In the case of DICOM files, a SortedDictionary is probably the best way to save the list of DICOM data elements.  It can keep them in the proper order by DICOM tag, and will supply random access to the tags.  You also probably want an indexer on the class to supply random access to the tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of open source JAVA-based DICOM implementations like [dcm4che2](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/d2/dcm4che2+DICOM+Toolkit). Have you considered porting their implementation?

Comment: Well not really. I want to learn from this by experience and not really by copying their implementation. If I'd do that I could just use that xD